# Error in function execution when button is clicked in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using python's tkinter library to build a GUI.

There are 4 buttons and a function that operates when clicked is defined for each button. That function does not work and the error `'MyFrame' object has no attribute 'toggleBTN_INVENTORY'` occurs.

My code is...

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font

class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("INVENTORY CONTROL PROGRAM")
        self.pack(fill = "both", expand=True)

        MODE = "INVENTORY"
        font01 = tkinter.font.Font(family="맑은 고딕", size = 25)
        font02 = tkinter.font.Font(family="맑은 고딕", size = 20)

        # MAIN MENU FRAME
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self, relief="solid")
        frame1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        toggleBTN_INVENTORY = tk.Button(self, padx = 40, pady = 1, text = "BTN A", font = font01, bg = "gray", command = self.INVENTORY_MODE)
        toggleBTN_INPUT     = tk.Button(self, padx = 40, pady = 1, text = "BTN B", font = font01, bg = "SystemButtonFace", command = self.INPUT_MODE)
        toggleBTN_OUTPUT    = tk.Button(self, padx = 40, pady = 1, text = "BTN C", font = font01, bg = "SystemButtonFace", command = self.OUTPUT_MODE)
        BTN_SEARCH          = tk.Button(self, padx = 40, pady = 1, text = "BTN D", font = font01, bg = "SystemButtonFace", command = self.SEARCH)

        SearchBox = tk.Entry(self, width = 30, font = font01)
        SearchBox.insert(0, " SEARCH")
        SearchBox.bind("<Button-1>", self.Click_SearchBox)

        toggleBTN_INVENTORY.grid(column = 0, row = 0, pady = 10)
        toggleBTN_INPUT.grid(column = 1, row = 0, pady = 10)
        toggleBTN_OUTPUT.grid(column = 2, row = 0)
        SearchBox.grid(column = 3, row = 0, ipady = 15)
        BTN_SEARCH.grid(column = 4, row = 0)

    
    def INVENTORY_MODE(self):
        MODE = "INVENTORY"
        self.toggleBTN_INVENTORY.config(bg = "gray")
        self.toggleBTN_INPUT.config(bg = "SystemButtonFace")
        self.toggleBTN_OUTPUT.config(bg = "SystemButtonFace")
        print(MODE)

    def INPUT_MODE(self):
        MODE = "INPUT"
        self.toggleBTN_INVENTORY.config(bg = "SystemButtonFace")
        self.toggleBTN_INPUT.config(bg = "gray")
        self.toggleBTN_OUTPUT.config(bg = "SystemButtonFace")
        print(MODE)

    def OUTPUT_MODE(self):
        MODE = "OUTPUT"
        self.toggleBTN_INVENTORY.config(bg = "SystemButtonFace")
        self.toggleBTN_INPUT.config(bg = "SystemButtonFace")
        self.toggleBTN_OUTPUT.config(bg = "gray")
        print(MODE)

def Click_SearchBox(event, self) :
    TEXT = self.SearchBox.get()
    if(TEXT == " SEARCH") :
        self.SearchBox.delete(0, "end")

def SEARCH(self):
    GET_SearchBox = self.SearchBox.get()
    print("SEARCH for [ " + GET_SearchBox + " ]")


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    app = MyFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I make the button function work?

Answer (score 2):

The `Button`s are only being assigned to **local variables** in the `__init__()` method. You need to make them **attributes** of the `MyFrame` instance by prefixing their names with "`self.`".

In addition to that, two of the referenced methods, `Click_SearchBox()` and `SEARCH()` were not indented properly within the `class` definition and were therefore not considered to part of the class which caused additional errors. I also noticed that the calling sequence you specified for the `Click_SearchBox()` was incorrect.

The code below has the corrections need to fix the problem you asked about and the others I encountered or notices. I also reformatting some of it to make it more readable by following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkfont


class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("INVENTORY CONTROL PROGRAM")
        self.pack(fill = "both", expand=True)

        MODE = "INVENTORY"
        font01 = tkfont.Font(family="맑은 고딕", size=25)
        font02 = tkfont.Font(family="맑은 고딕", size=20)

        # MAIN MENU FRAME
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self, relief="solid")
        frame1.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.toggleBTN_INVENTORY = tk.Button(self, padx=40, pady=1, text="BTN A",
                                             font=font01, bg="gray",
                                             command=self.INVENTORY_MODE)
        self.toggleBTN_INPUT = tk.Button(self, padx=40, pady=1, text="BTN B", font=font01,
                                         bg="SystemButtonFace", command=self.INPUT_MODE)
        self.toggleBTN_OUTPUT = tk.Button(self, padx=40, pady=1, text="BTN C",
                                          font=font01, bg="SystemButtonFace",
                                          command=self.OUTPUT_MODE)
        self.BTN_SEARCH = tk.Button(self, padx=40, pady=1, text="BTN D", font=font01,
                                    bg="SystemButtonFace", command=self.SEARCH)

        self.SearchBox = tk.Entry(self, width=30, font=font01)
        self.SearchBox.insert(0, " SEARCH")
        self.SearchBox.bind("<Button-1>", self.Click_SearchBox)

        self.toggleBTN_INVENTORY.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=10)
        self.toggleBTN_INPUT.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=10)
        self.toggleBTN_OUTPUT.grid(column=2, row=0)
        self.SearchBox.grid(column=3, row=0, ipady=15)
        self.BTN_SEARCH.grid(column=4, row=0)

    def INVENTORY_MODE(self):
        MODE = "INVENTORY"
        self.toggleBTN_INVENTORY.config(bg="gray")
        self.toggleBTN_INPUT.config(bg="SystemButtonFace")
        self.toggleBTN_OUTPUT.config(bg="SystemButtonFace")
        print(MODE)

    def INPUT_MODE(self):
        MODE = "INPUT"
        self.toggleBTN_INVENTORY.config(bg="SystemButtonFace")
        self.toggleBTN_INPUT.config(bg="gray")
        self.toggleBTN_OUTPUT.config(bg="SystemButtonFace")
        print(MODE)

    def OUTPUT_MODE(self):
        MODE = "OUTPUT"
        self.toggleBTN_INVENTORY.config(bg="SystemButtonFace")
        self.toggleBTN_INPUT.config(bg="SystemButtonFace")
        self.toggleBTN_OUTPUT.config(bg="gray")
        print(MODE)

    def Click_SearchBox(self, event) :
        TEXT = self.SearchBox.get()
        if TEXT == " SEARCH":
            self.SearchBox.delete(0, "end")

    def SEARCH(self):
        GET_SearchBox = self.SearchBox.get()
        print("SEARCH for [ " + GET_SearchBox + " ]")


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    app = MyFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```